# How to retrieve the Date variable from oracle database in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format and store in Date variable in the same format?

Tags: java, date

I want to retrieve the Date object from oracle database and store it in Date variable in Java in the same format ?

PS ; Data type of the variable should be Date only but, need to have the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss .

Comment: You've just given requirements. Consider adding some code with what you already tried, a description of your problem, and a **question**.

Comment: if the datatype in your database does not contain HH:mm:ss then it will default to 12 AM, if you retrieve the value and convert it to your format using the Date class in java you will get this result.

Comment: A `Date` has no format - it's just a number of milliseconds since the 1st of January 1970 UTC.

Answer (score 1):

`Date` class will store internally the date as a long integer. If you want to convert it to string you can use a `DateFormat`

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String dateFormatted = df.format(new Date());
Date date = df.parse(dateFormatted);
```

Comment: I have to retain the data type "Date" while storing the date in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format.

Comment: Can you post some sample code of what you've attempted? I'm not familiar with Oracle DB, but shouldn't be much different to MySQL and a Date type should exist to store dates, instead of using a String for it. In any case I think that you should be able to convert t to `String` using the code that I provided to send it to the DB Driver. Also, it'd be different if you're using Hibernate or Eclipselink...

Comment: In ur above example, it will give the output in Thu May 04 12:44:18 CEST 2017 format. But, I need it in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format while printing the Date variable.

Comment: You'll not achieve that unless you override the `toString()` method of `Date`. You'll see the proper value if you print `dateFormatted` from my example

Answer (score 1):

If the database is set up correctly, you should be able to simply retrieve a date column into a date variable.  Formatting considerations should be non-applicable at the database access level; they should be a non-issue.

Formatting is something you do in order to display the date to the user.

Formatting is also something that various tools do, to show you the contents of your database, or the contents of your date object, so this can cause a bit of confusion, as it may lead you to believe that the date column has a certain format, or that your date variable has a certain format.  But they don't.

The problems start when things are done wrongly at the database level.  If the database column is not actually of a temporal data type, but of `CHAR` type instead, then of course formatting plays a role. But then we are not talking about "Retrieving a date object from the oracle database", we are talking about retrieving a string from the database and converting it to a date. However, you have no told us nothing about the structure of your table, so we cannot speculate about that.

So, with the information that you have given, the right answer is simply "just fetch the date column into a date variable".  Please provide more information if you need a different answer.

Comment: Good and informative answer. If you have the newest JDBC driver, you should be able to retrieve the date into a `LocalDate` rather than an outdated `Date`. The information in the answer still applies.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, you might want to create a `CustomDate` class that prints the value in the specified format:

```
public class CustomDate extends Date{
    private static final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return df.format(this);
    }

}
```

Instead of creating instances of Date, try to use CustomDate. It'll be equivalent in your code.